# Development console commands registration

Tags: c#, design-patterns, programming-practices

I have a DevelopmentConsole class. I am making functionality to register console commands for the subsystems. I don't want the console to know about them but also I don't want them to contain a debug code (like "Console.RegisterCommand...").

I think I should make an additional class hiearachy. For an example I have Player class.

```
IConsoleBuilder { 
    RegisterCommand(string command, Func<string[], string> action); 
}

PlayerConsoleBuilderClient : ConsoleBuilderClient { 
    readonly Player _player =  ?inject?

    public override void Visit(IConsoleBuilder builder) { 
        // builder.RegisterCommand("GetName", args => _player.Name) ; 
    }
}
```

Here I need to use Reflection to find all ConsoleBuilderClient subclasses. It's not a very good idea, is it?

Can you suggest how to do it in a better way?

Comment: Why is it not a good idea? Reflection is bad because it's slow and can be a bit unmaintainable. If you're just doing it at startup, the speed shouldn't matter. And this is simple enough that the unmaintainability is likely to not have a huge impact.

Comment: @Telastyn Because I should enumerate all types (possible in all appdomain assemblies) to find these subclasses. Too slow.

Comment: @Vlad: why do you think its too slow (executed just once at the startup)? Did you measure it?

Comment: @Vlad: when I understand your question correctly, you want your console to loop over all ConsoleBuilderClient subclasses, instantiate one object of that class and call the "Visit" method. Is that correct? If yes: in your example above, it looks as if there could be different objects of type `PlayerConsoleBuilderClient`, each object corresponds to a different command. How does that fit together? Looks for me like your are mixing objects and classes, but maybe I misunderstood something.

Comment: @DocBrown
"Is that correct?" - yes.
"it looks as if there could be different objects of type" - no, I don't need a seperate class for every specific command but only for subsystem commands. I create only one instance of each BuilderClient subclass and use each of instance to register multple commands.

It's to slow because I have to enumerate **all** types to compare BaseType property. I think ~200 ms. What if I have more than one system like this?

Comment: @Vlad: well, I don't know the overall structure of your system, but can't you restrict the search for subclasses to a small (configurable) set of assemblies? That means you won't have to to enumerate *all* types, only the ones in those assemblies. Or do you expect the assemblies containing those builder class to be "hot-plugged" after deployment?

Comment: @Vlad: and if performance of reflection really bothers you (what I still find hard to believe), and you don't want to set up a collection of objects manually like described in Euphoric's answers, you could write a tool which determines the relevant subclasses *as part of your build process*, and generates the code for instantiation of an object of each of that classes automatically. So the reflection part would be only executed once (almost "at compile time"), not in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only 2 options. You either explicitly define each client class in some kind of collection. Probably in some kind of topmost project. Or you use reflection to look for all subclasses of ConsoleBuilderClient in all loaded/available assemblies.

It is up to you to pick which one you prefer.